# Do you need any special image for getting Parallax effect in Materialize.css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I am using [Materialize CSS.](http://materializecss.com/parallax.html)

My code :

```
<div class="parallax-container">
    <div class="parallax">
        <img src="../../public/assets/img/mount.jpg" />        
    </div>    
</div>

<div class="parallax-container">
    <div class="parallax">
         <img src="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/landscape-georgia.jpg">
     </div>   
</div>
```

Only the second image seems to get a parallax effect while scrolling whereas the first one seems to move with the same speed.
`mount.jpg` is just a random image in my computer.

And.. of course I did initialize parallax in javascript.

`$('.parallax').parallax();`

Comment: can you show a fiddle example?

Comment: sure ! 1 sec hold on

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nmdd876c/ .. but the image is not showing up in fiddle at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I update your Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/nmdd876c/2/

Everything's fine. I only clean-up your html & correct your external resources.

```
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

I even try different images & it's working fine.

Comment: Have you used any special image ? Or will it work with normal images also ?

Comment: I tried it with `jpg`, `jpeg`, & `png` & it works fine. I believe it will still work even on `bmp` or `gif`.

Comment: What are the other changes that you did ?  Yours is working perfect !

Comment: Even I tried correcting my resources but output is not like yours

Comment: Did you check your image path? On your fiddle, I only correct your resources & add some images online for testing. https://jsfiddle.net/nmdd876c/4/ check your jQuery ^2.1.0 if it's also included on your page. Also, you can check your console if there's an error on your page & share it here

Comment: Got it ! Thanks so much